# Sorting by virtual field in mongoDB (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

Let's say I have some Schema which has a virtual field like this

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name: { type: String }
},
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

schema.virtual("name_length").get(function(){
    return this.name.length;
});
```

In a query is it possible to sort the results by the virtual field? Something like

```
schema.find().sort("name_length").limit(5).exec(function(docs){ ... });
```

When I try this, the results are simple not sorted...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You won't be able to sort by a virtual field because they are not stored to the database.

> Virtual attributes are attributes that are convenient to have around
>   but that do not get persisted to mongodb.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

Comment: I know what virtual attributes are and that they are not stored in db. I was wandering maybe there might be some plugin or special method that calls all the getters for virtual attributes and then sorts docs.
I guess there is no such thing.

Comment: So, I guess my solution should be to sort and limit in javascript after getting results?

Comment: and I guess you cannot use virtuals in find condition?

Comment: depends how many records you have... you will basically have to retrieve *all* items, then sort. Which, if you have millions / want to page results, will be inefficient

Comment: well I think there might be not millions but thousands of results and I need to sort them...

Comment: Can't you just persist the name_length to the document? Then you can sort on this db side.... do it when inserting / updating document?

Comment: unfortunately my real case is more complicated than the name thing. My virtual is being calculated depending on logged in user info.

Comment: Arvan, it's been an eternity, but same exact problem here, I need a computed field depending on other fields and I must use it as sort field. Any solution ?

Comment: This answer just says its not possible. Has anyone found a way to sort by a virtual attribute? In my case `array.length`

Comment: @chovy since a virtual property isn't stored in mongodb you'll have to do this after querying, or store the value of array.length as an actual property.

Answer (score 4):

Virtuals defined in the Schema are not injected into the generated MongoDB queries. The functions defined are simply run for each document at the appropriate moments, once they have already been retrieved from the database.

In order to reach what you're trying to achieve, you'll also need to define the virtual field within the MongoDB query. For example, in the $project stage of an aggregation.

There are, however, a few things to keep in mind when sorting by virtual fields:

- projected documents are only available in memory, so it would come with a huge performance cost if we just add a field and have the entire documents of the search results in memory before sorting
- because of the above, indexes will not be used at all when sorting

Here's a general example on how to sort by virtual fields while keeping a relatively good performance:

Imagine you have a collection of teams and each team contains an array of players directly stored into the document. Now, the requirement asks for us to sort those teams by the ranking of the favoredPlayer where the favoredPlayer is basically a virtual property containing the most relevant player of the team under certain criteria (in this example we only want to consider offense and defense players). Also, the aforementioned criteria depend on the users' choices and can, therefore, not be persisted into the document.

To top it off, our "team" document is pretty large, so in order to mitigate the performance hit of sorting in-memory, we project only the fields we need for sorting and then restore the original document after limiting the results.

The query:

```json
[
  // find all teams from germany
  { '$match': { country: 'de' } },
  // project only the sort-relevant fields
  // and add the virtual favoredPlayer field to each team
  { '$project': {
    rank: 1,
    'favoredPlayer': {
      '$arrayElemAt': [
        {
          // keep only players that match our criteria
          $filter: {
            input: '$players',
            as: 'p',
            cond: { $in: ['$$p.position', ['offense', 'defense']] },
          },
        },
        // take first of the filtered players since players are already sorted by relevance in our db
        0,
      ],
    },
  }},
  // sort teams by the ranking of the favoredPlayer
  { '$sort': { 'favoredPlayer.ranking': -1, rank: -1 } },
  { '$limit': 10 },
  // $lookup, $unwind, and $replaceRoot are in order to restore the original database document
  { '$lookup': { from: 'teams', localField: '_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'subdoc' } },
  { '$unwind': { path: '$subdoc' } },
  { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$subdoc' } },
];
```

For the example you gave above, the code could look something like the following:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  { name: { type: String } },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  });

schema.virtual('name_length').get(function () {
  return this.name.length;
});

const MyModel = mongoose.model('Thing', schema);

MyModel
  .aggregate()
  .project({
    'name_length': {
      '$strLenCP': '$name',
    },
  })
  .sort({ 'name_length': -1 })
  .exec(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
  });
```