# How to sort by the value of number1 plus number2 in the mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I prepare get some objects in the mongodb.

```
{number1:123,number2:321}
{number1:222,number2:4532}
```

For example, these are what i have in the database. But now, i want to get them by the value of number1 + number2.

How to do it ?

Comment: Please include the code/query that you used to get this output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option that no one has actually said here is to use the aggregation framework. Better than using `$where` since it will be faster and you can actually sort on that return and more as such:

```
db.c.aggregate([
    {'$project': {sumField: {$add: ['$number1', '$number2']}}},
    {'$sort': {sumField: 1}}
]);
```

Like so. Better than using the inbuilt JS, plus with an index and covered query you could make this faster since aggregation, unlike `$where` can actually use an index.

Answer (score 1):

Use $where operator
`db.myCollection.find( {'$where':'this.number1 + this.number2 = 200'})`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a virtual to your schema in mongodb will help you

```
YourSchema.virtual('numbersum')
.get(function () {
  return this.number1 + ' ' + this.number2;
})
```

Then, you´ll be able to do that:

```
db.yourcollection.find().sort({numbersum:1});
```

Check this answer.  [Sorting by virtual field in mongoDB (mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452795/sorting-by-virtual-field-in-mongodb-mongoose)

**EDIT** this will work only when using mongoose as connector